# Obtain device phone number with Trigger.IO Forge on Android / iOS

Tags: trigger.io

I would like to get the device phone number in my Android / iOS mobile app compiled with Trigger.io Forge. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible via an existing Forge module. So to do this you'd need to write a native plugin.